# How to calculate the average of a column using other columns as a reference using excel

Tags: r, excel, mean

I have three columns in excel `year`, `month` `value`.

I want to average `value` considering `month` and `year`. In R language this function is done by group_by(). In excel how could this be done?

```
year    month   value
2019    1   12
2019    1   34
2019    2   56
2019    2   15
2020    1   16
2020    3   67
2020    4   89
2018    6   123
2018    6   45
2018    7   98
2019    3   53
2019    1   23
2020    1   12
2020    3   1
```

Comment: Have a look at averageif() and averageifs().

Answer (score 1):

If one has Office 365 we can use:

```
=LET(
    y,A2:A15,
    m,B2:B15,
    v,C2:C15,
    u,SORT(UNIQUE(CHOOSE({1,2},y,m)),{1,2}),
    CHOOSE({1,1,2},u,AVERAGEIFS(v,y,INDEX(u,0,1),m,INDEX(u,0,2))))
```

Put this in the first cell and it will spill the results.

[image]

Once the HSTACK is release we can replace the CHOOSE with it:

```
=LET(
    y,A2:A15,
    m,B2:B15,
    v,C2:C15,
    u,SORT(UNIQUE(HSTACK(y,m)),{1,2}),
    HSTACK(u,AVERAGEIFS(v,y,INDEX(u,0,1),m,INDEX(u,0,2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Averageifs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256534?hl=en) would do what you want, but you might want to review using the [Filter function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) to duplicate the Group_By() method for other similar procedures. Once grouped, you can sum/average/sort, etc.

Averageifs:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C:C,A:A,2018,B:B,6)
```

Filter:

```
=filter(C:C,(A:A=2018)*(B:B=6))
=Average(filter(C:C,(A:A=2018)*(B:B=6)))
```

See [this spreadsheet for examples of both](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Frk7MRUzU_YNNf5bQorXGku3hi5CgPs7YPz7RDOQSRE/edit?usp=sharing). I realize you're using Excel, but these formulas should work on both (though they are not the same)